# Какая ошибка что делать

Tags: python, discord.py

Код

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
bot.remove_command( 'help' )
token = 'Токен бота'

@bot.command()
async def приват(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ОТПРАВИТЕЛЬ: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}
    await guild.create_text_channel("Приватный-канал", overwrites=overwrites)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot started...")
bot.run(token)
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Не", line 3, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: Если дословно перевести ошибку `missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`, то вполне ясно что ожидается параметр `intents` который вы не указали.

Comment: Как его добавить?

Comment: https://www.pythondiscord.com/pages/tags/intents/

Comment: Ошибка `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 3, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
                                                   ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'intents' is not defined`

Comment: Значит не объявили переменную intents, но уже передаете ее.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не добавили интенты при инициализации , добавить их можно следующим образом:

```
intents=discord.Intents.all()
```

Также нельзя давать функциям имена на русском языке, но можно прописать его в name в декораторе @bot.command:

```
async def приват(ctx):
```

замените на:

```
@bot.command(name='приват')
async def private(ctx)
```

И мой вам совет, пишите дискорд ботов на disnake.